# Cannot use class on in a require

Tags: php, symfony

Hey everyone I'm making a little webiste with the silex php microframework and I have a problem that I can't understand! So here is my question !

If I use this at the top of my main php file :

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

and then I later require these files : 
 
require 'phpFiles/login.php'; 
require 'phpFiles/register.php';

Why can't i use the top classes in the code of my required class ?
I dont want to add these 2 use line to every single php file I require

Hope you guys understand my question !

Comment: Without more context you're unlikely to get any meaningful help.

Comment: Well I'm just wondering why you cant access the classes i called from my require files

Comment: You're using Symfony framework. If you want to include a bunch of files you have to do it the symfony way.

Comment: If the autoloader isn't on deck then your use statements are meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not like you "can't use the top classes" in the included files. It's just that the included files don't inherit the parent file's importing/aliasing rules defined with `use` because those are **per-file basis only**. If you want to be able to refer to `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` with just `Request` in the included files, you need to use `use` in those as well. Your only other option is using fully qualified names.